# Is it possible to use Discord slash commands as module?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

First things first, I'm a beginner in node.js and discord.js.

I'm currently working on my own discord bot for fun and I was wondering if it was possible to "store" the data of a slash command. Here is an example of what I mean :

```
    const response = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .properties()
      .properties()
      etc...
    
    module.exports = () {
      const data = {
        data: {
          type: 4, // I don't know what type to use  for embed message so please correct me if I'm wrong
          data: {
            content: response
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Could this be possible to "store" the embed message data in `rules.js` and use it in `main.js` like so :

```
    const rules = require('rules.js') //the file would be in a "commands" folder but I'm keeping this simple

    client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction) => {
      const command = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase()
      if (command === 'rules') {
        client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post(data) // or post(rules.data) ??? again, I'm a beginner
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can try:

```js
//file name: slashCmd.js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = async function(client, cmdObj) {
     client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.post(cmdObj)
}
```

You can customize the function as much as you want but you can do this in your index.js

```js
const slashCmd = require('./slashCmd.js');
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.on('ready', () => {
    slashCmd(client, {
        name: 'cmdName',
        description: 'cmdDesc'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a function instead of save and export module because is dangerous to use instance class like a module because it's causing a memory issue, so write a factory for this